# Road to production with Instagram graph API - business discovery

Tags: instagram-graph-api

###### USE CASE

I´m developing **background service** which will **periodically collect metrics** from business and creator Instagram accounts. Example use case: **Collect metrics every 2 weeks from around 1000 instagram accounts and get 1 month old posts for each IG account.** As you can see:

- I´m using only **business_discovery** together with **media** edge from *Instagram graph API*.
- App will be not used by any person from inside or outside organization, just with administrator account

###### CURRENT STATE

Right now I use testing Facebook developer App with my own testing Instagram account. So far I understand how API works, hot to get data, how to use paging, limiting and how to get data I want. I need just following permissions `instagram_basic` and `instagram_manage_insights`. Let's assume that I will create facebook developer app for customer I work for with all needed steps to get to the point where I'm now with my testing app.
**I do not understand following:**

1. **App review**
   In documentation is stated: `If your app will only be used by app users who have a Role on your app or Business, you do not need to complete App Review.`
   App will be used just by administrator of the app. => `I do not need App review`... BUT, is `standard access` for `instagram_basic` and `instagram_manage_insights` permissions sufficient for my use case?
2. **Business review**
   In documentation is stated: `You must complete Business Verification if your app will be used by app users who do not have a Role on the app itself, or a Role in a Business that has claimed the app.`
   App will be used just by administrator of the app. => `I do not need Business review`
3. **App Mode** Development vs live
   App mode can be changed on facebook developer App dashboard. It has following description: `In Development mode, your app can only request data from users with an app role. To request end user data, your app must have Advanced Access permissions and be set to Live mode.`
   Do I need to switch to `live mode` for my use case? I already can request data from end users.
   In order to switch to live mode, I need to fill `Privacy Policy URL`, but nobody is using my app, I do not have any privacy policy URL.
4. **Aceess token**
   In documentation for business discovery API is stated: `A Facebook User access token with the following permissions:`
   The user access token lasts just for one hour! I can make long lived access token, which lasts about 60 days. Does the token life time reset to 60 days each time when I make request?
   My app is bacground service which will be used just with administration account. I would like to generate infinite access token, or generate it once a year max.
5. **Rate limits**
   In documentation is stated: `Business Discovery and Hashtag Search are subject to Platform Rate Limits.`
   Platform Rate Limits:
   `Calls within one hour = 200 * Number of Users`
   In my use case `Number of Users` is equal to 1? So I can make only 200 calls per hour? Is it possible to increase this limit?
   When I tested this limit I encountered another limitation. And that is `total_time` from `X-App-Usage` header.
   `Total Time: The length of time the request takes to process. When total_time reaches 100, calls may be throttled.`
   I have reached 100% `total_time` before reaching 200 requests/hour limit. I have spammed the API too fast I guess. Does have anyone experiences with this? Should I implement logic with small sleep between each api request?

**It follows from what I have written so far:**
I don't need App review, business review, live mode. I only have 200 api calls per hour and I can't spam the API due to the `total_time' restriction. I have to use a long lived token which I need to refresh every 60 days(Please tell me this is not true!) ?

Comment: I am in a similar situation. How did you did it finally?